# Are E-mail verification with keys made from python uuid.uuid4 a good approach?

Tags: python, web-applications, uuid, email-verification

I would like to make e-mail verification in my website.

I plan to send an email to the user with a link to verify the email address, wherein verification link I plan to include a key made with:

```py
str(uuid.uuid4())
```

The verification link will expire after some time.

My questions:

is it good aproach? safe, reliable?
do I have to check either uuid.uuid4() is unique?
are uuid.uuid4() values safe for being parts of URL?

Comment: This will be closed as too broad, but you could try asking this on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it good aproach? safe, reliable? do I have to check either uuid.uuid4() is unique? are uuid.uuid4() values safe for being parts of URL?

Yes, this should be sufficient enough for email verification.

According to [Georg Schölly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785592/369450),

> uuid4() generates ... a random UUID. The chance of a collision is really, really, really small. Small enough, that you shouldn't worry about it. The problem is, that a bad random-number generator makes it more likely to have collisions.

Who then quoted [Bob Aman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/786541/369450),

> Frankly, in a single application space without malicious actors, the extinction of all life on earth will occur long before you have a collision, even on a version 4 UUID, even if you're generating quite a few UUIDs per second.

So I would say this is safe and reliable for email verification. And there should not be a need to make sure the UUID4 is unique (but I couldn't hurt to check when generating it). Also, as long as the UUID is hex-encoded (its canonical form), it is safe for being part of a URL.