# When is it appropriate to use UUIDs for a web project?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, uuid

I'm busy with the database design of a new project, and I'm not sure whether to use UUIDs or normal table-unique auto-increment ids.

Up to now, the sites I've built have all run on a single server, and very heavy traffic has never been too much of a concern. However, this web application will eventually run concurrently on multiple servers, serve an API, and need to process thousands of requests per second, and I want to make sure that the design I choose now doesn't cripple any of those possibilities later.

I have my suspicions, of course, and they should be clear through the way I phrased my question, but I would like to hear from those with more experience what trouble I can run into later if I do or don't have UUIDs, and what I should really be basing my decision on.

So, **in short**: What are the considerations I should give into deciding whether or not to use UUIDs for all database models, so that any one object can be identified uniquely by one string, and when is it appropriate to use this as the primary key, instead of table-by-table auto-increment?

*Note*: I've seen [this question (When are you truly forced to use UUID as part of the design?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703035/), and read all the answers, but they mostly answer "How rarely do UUIDs collide", instead of "When is it appropriate to use them".

Answer (score 5):

One consideration that I've used when deciding on UUIDs vs. auto-increment ids is whether they're going to be user-visible, and if so, whether I want users to know how many I have of that table. For example, if I didn't want to make public the number of registered users my site has, I wouldn't assign auto-increment user ids.

And to address one other specific point you raised, it's still possible to use auto-incrementing ids with multiple servers (though not with the built-in MySQL). You just need to start all the ids at different offsets, and increment accordingly. That is, if you had 3 servers, you could start server A at 1, server B at 2, and server C at 3, and then increment the ids by 10 each time instead of 1. That way, you could guarantee no collisions.

And finally, the last thing I consider is how important performance is to my application. Integers are much more easily indexed than UUIDs that are string-based, so indexes are smaller, more quickly searched, etc.

Answer (score 3):

UUID's or GUID's can be very useful especially for the web. If you use auto-increment values to store UserId anyone can view the source of your web pages and see the simplicity of it's use. They could then try any integer value to get data they are not supposed to see.

GUID's are not created in any sequential format, therefore if you create them one right after the other, there sequence can not easily be guessed.

I don't think it's necessary to use GUID's for simple lookup type data such as ColorId 1=Blue, 2=Red, 3=Green.

GUID's are also very useful for session and state management.

That's my $0.02