# Django model fields unique=True and default=function

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique

So I have a model that looks like this

```
def create_invite_code():
  return str(uuid.uuid4())[0:8]

class InviteCodes(models.Model): 
  id = models.CharField(max_length = 36, primary_key = True, default=build_uuid)      
  code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=create_invite_code)
```

What happens if create_invite_code returns a code that already exists in the db, will django call the function again until it finds one that doesn't exist? Or will it error out?

Comment: Python will raise `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`. In your `create_invite_code` function return constant string and test it yourself.

Comment: ok gotcha why dont you post this as an answer and I will make it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code field in your model `InviteCodes` is a unique field. If you tries to create another entry with an already existing code, then python will raise `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` exception.

You can test it by returning a constant string from `create_invite_code` function. For example,

```
def create_invite_code():
  return 'test'
```

The first entry will be unique, but in the second call the exception will be raised.

Answer (score 1):

As people said here, it will raise "UNIQUE constraint failed" integrity error. Which could potentially happen cause you're not doing any check for uniqueness.

I would recommend django-uuidfield by David Cramer. It handles all the validation for you.

https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield

Comment: Im not worried about the uuid field id because of this post, I want the random 8 letter code to be safe. Which django-uuidfield wont do for me. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703035/when-are-you-truly-forced-to-use-uuid-as-part-of-the-design/786541#786541