# How to prevent IntegrityError in case of using UUID in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, uuid, database-integrity

I want to use UUID as PK in my django model as follows (database is Postgresql):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pk = models.UUID(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

Every time `uuid.uuid4` generates a new UUID. 
My question is: Is it possible that `uuid.uuid4` generate a duplicate UUID?
And if it's possible, how to prevent IntegrityError in case of duplicate UUID generated?

Comment: Check this article out: [Are UUIDs really unique?](https://towardsdatascience.com/are-uuids-really-unique-57eb80fc2a87), you don't really need to be concerned, the chances of that happening are **really really** low.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes I know the probability is low. But I want to find a solution for preventing this really really low probability.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make sure you are not compromising your database but still using the UUID as an identifier is to do the following:

```
# Or whatever field name suits you best / unique=True for integrity purposes
uuid_pk = models.UUID(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Just make it a secondary key and unique and use the pk provided by Django as normal.

Comment: It is not the solution. Adding `unique=True` doesn't solve the problem. just raises IntegrityError if duplicate UUID generated, the main problem I have.

Comment: UUID by default is ``not guaranteed unique but practically unique`` but there is one way that you can make it so, override the save method when saving your instance and add a auto-incremental value to your uuid field,

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer by Bob Aman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703035/when-are-you-truly-forced-to-use-uuid-as-part-of-the-design/786541#786541)

> Frankly, in a single application space
> without malicious actors, the
> extinction of all life on earth will
> occur long before you have a
> collision, even on a version 4 UUID,
> even if you're generating quite a few
> UUIDs per second.

You really don't need to worry about any duplicates, if you still worry try using **uuid1** instead, which has even lesser chances of having duplicates as it uses the machines MAC and timestamps. You can always use a try-except block to check for IntegrityErrors if needed.